# Custom HTML Form Input To Change Value

Tags: jquery, html

I have seen this many places. **The scrolling changes value.**

[image]

**How to create this in html and what is this called?**

**Edit:
People are thinking its a dropdown but that arrow moves left to right and value gets changed.**

Comment: It's custom dropdown with scroll listener. Use js/jQuery for that.

Comment: It's called `<select>` attribute

Comment: any idea how to make?

Comment: If you want the style like that, you will need to have the css rules. But to create a simple `<select>` see this [link](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_select.asp)

Comment: thats not select. I am asking about slider that arrow moves left to right.

Comment: @Phonix that's made using slider component, take a look at the updated answer using slider.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated example using slider

Here's an example.

```js
var steps = [
    "one",
    "two",
    "three",
    "four",
    "five"
];

$(function() {
    $(".slider").slider({
        value: 0,
        min: 0,
        max: 4,
        step: 1,
        slide: function(event, ui) {
            $(".b").html(steps[ui.value]);
        }
    });
    $(".b").val(steps[$(".slider").slider("value")]);
});
```

```css
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300,600,700,800);
html,body{
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  background-color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  color: #212121;
}
h1{
  text-transform: capitalize;
  font-weight: 100;
  font-size: 42px;
  border-bottom: 1px dashed  #ccc;
  
  padding-bottom: 30px;
  color: #454545;
}
.container{
  max-width: 80%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.ui-state-default, .ui-widget-content .ui-state-default, .ui-widget-header .ui-state-default{
  
  background-color: #fff;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
  -moz-border-radius: 50%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  
}
.ui-state-default, .ui-widget-content .ui-state-default, .ui-widget-header .ui-state-default{
  background: none;
}
.ui-slider-horizontal .ui-slider-handle{
  top: -.5em;
}
.ui-slider-horizontal{
  height: .4em;
  border: 0;
  background-color: #e8e8e8;
  
  
}
.b{
  margin-top:20px;
  font-weight: 100;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #00CEAF;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 30px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  min-width: 200px;
  transition: all .3s;
  font-size: 20px;
  
  &:hover{
    background-color: darken(#00CEAF,5%);
    
  }
}

  
    height: 1.2em;
    width: 1.2em;

    background-color: #00CEAF  ;
      &:hover,&:focus,&:active{
    background-color: #00CEAF;
        
  }
  }

.ui-state-default, .ui-widget-content .ui-state-default, .ui-widget-header .ui-state-default{border-color: #a3a3a3;}
.ui-state-default, .ui-widget-content .ui-state-default, .ui-widget-header .ui-state-default{
     -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: #a3a3a3;
  outline: 0;
  &:hover,&:focus,&:active{
    outline: 0;
    background-color: #00CEAF;
    border-color:  #00CEAF;
  }
  &:hover{
    background-color: #fff;
    &:active{
      background-color: #00CEAF;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <h1>Current value is : </h1>
<div class="b">one</div>
<div class="slider"></div>
```

Comment: I am not asking about dropdown. i am trying to make that slider thing.

Comment: Thanks this is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this with HTML.

If you want to use a form for option select with HTML you can do something like this:

```
<select>
  <option value="1">One</option> 
  <option value="2">Two</option> 
</select>
```

To design the form with the colors and shapes you like you can use CSS.
You can also use some dropdown plugin.